# How can I open links from w3m in firefox?

Tags: w3m

I'd like to open links from `w3m` in Firefox. I've followed the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/a/422706/125959) (and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/333862/how-do-i-open-a-link-from-an-email-in-mutt-without-using-the-mouse/333921?noredirect=1#comment1352078_333921)), but cannot get it working.

I've also tried a few other permutations in the `external browser` field of the settings page (accessed by <kbd>o</kbd>):

- `firefox`
- `/usr/bin/firefox`
- `/usr/bin/firefox %s`
- `/usr/bin/firefox`

After pressing `[OK]` in the settings page, I've gone back and verified that the setting has been saved. However, when I attempt to open a link with <kbd>M</kbd> then selecting the link; or the current page with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>; nothing happens.

(Previously asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/983201/how-can-i-open-links-from-w3m-in-firefox-redux) with no response.)

Comment: What have you got in your configs?

Comment: Perhaps DISPLAY is not set in the environment?

Comment: @jasonwryan It's a totally fresh install. Just to double-check, I deleted `~/.w3m/config`, changed `external browser` as above, and tested again. It still failed. Having said that, I also just noticed that links break over line-breaks (when calling w3m from mutt with `<pipe-entry>'w3m'<enter>`). I'm just looking for a way to open urls from mutt! (And I share your frustration with html email!)

Comment: @meuh `DISPLAY` is `:0`. (I checked from the command line, and also from within mutt, where I'm calling `w3m` from.)

Comment: Well, the setting is `extbrowser`. But you can also use another approach with [urxvt-perls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls) (if you use Urxvt as your terminal).

Comment: @jasonwryan I changed the settings via the GUI, but the config does contain `extbrowser /usr/bin/firefox`. (I use terminator as my terminal.)

Comment: Please paste your config. Here is mine as a reference: https://bitbucket.org/jasonwryan/shiv/src/tip/.w3m/config?at=&fileviewer=file-view-default#config-66

Comment: Do you have this problem only when running w3m from mutt, or also when running w3m from an xterm/gnome-terminal/konsole/…? If you replace `firefox` by `xmessage`, what does `M` do?

Comment: @jasonwryan http://pastebin.com/Nr1vCrnj

Comment: That looks fine (assuming you have altered the keymaps). I still don't think it will do what you want. Test it outside mutt and then in a rendered HTML email. See my answer for the details.

Comment: @Gilles I have this problem both when running from `mutt` and also when running in terminator with (say) `w3m google.com`. Replacing with `xmessage` does nothing… BUT I've just noticed that it *will* pop up a message with <Shift>+M or <Esc>, <Shift>+M. It still does nothing without shift though, and I can never select anything from the <Esc>+M popup. If I revert the settings to `firefox`, then the <Shift>-ed versions work (but not the popup).

Comment: @Sparhawk The key binding is `M`, not `m`, so you need to press <Shift>+<M>! The `m` key toggles mouse support. Was your problem merely that you were typing the wrong key?

Comment: @Gilles I guess so! In general, I see `M` as meaning unshifted `m`, unless it explicitly says <Shift>+<M>. The two links at the top of my question didn't mention <Shift> at all! Also, <Esc>+M (with no shift) brings up a list of urls, so I thought that it was doing something right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reflection, I think you are approaching this the wrong way.

w3m is used to render HTML messages in mutt; but that doesn't mean that you will easily be able to open links in the *rendered HTML* (moving your cursor to the link, for example, is only possible with the mouse).

Instead, you could either use a Perl script like [extracturl](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/perl-extract-url)<sup>1</sup> or, if your terminal supports it, something like [urxvt-perls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls).

<sup>1. Link to the AUR package. Upstream is here: https://code.google.com/p/extracturl/</sup>

Comment: Hm… I had already tried `extracturl-git` from the AUR. I think they are the same thing? I re-installed with your PKGBUILD anyway, with the mutt 1.5.x [macro](http://www.memoryhole.net/~kyle/extract_url/) . When I press <Ctrl>+b, mutt flashes but appears to do nothing. Only when I quit mutt do I see a list of urls printed in the terminal. Is that how it's meant to work? I expected a more immediate display.

Comment: @Sparhawk No: it should open (immediately) in the foreground, allowing you to select the URL to send to $BROWSER. What macro are you using to trigger it?

Comment: The one from my link in the comment above, i.e `macro index,pager \cb "<enter-command> set my_pdsave=\$pipe_decode<enter> <enter-command> unset pipe_decode<enter> <pipe-message>extract_url.pl<enter> <enter-command> set pipe_decode=\$my_pdsave<enter>" "get URLs"`

Comment: It works for me: not sure what in your config is breaking it, but the macro looks OK.

Comment: Are you running vanilla mutt? I'm using `mutt-sidebar` from the AUR; I'm not sure if that's relevant. If we're on different versions, could you please post `mutt -v`? Mine is [here](http://pastebin.com/Y7Bp4Ekh).

Comment: I'm on vanilla: https://ptpb.pw/enXQ

Comment: Hm… seems almost identical. Not sure where else to look. (Also, thanks for the introduction to ptpb! It looks great!)

Comment: UUUUggghhhh… I had `set   wait_key = no` in `muttrc`. Removing this makes it work. (+1) However, it still annoys me that I have to switch to mouse to click the link. I feel like I might as well pipe it straight into Firefox.

Comment: @Sparhawk You shouldn't need the mouse *at all* (with extracturl), only if you are using w3m's extbrowser--which is why I recommended the alternate approach.

Comment: Perhaps it's still not working then. I hit `<Ctrl>`+`b`, then I drop back to the terminal, with a list of urls, and mutt's `Press any key to continue...`. I can't type anything except to exit. (Also, I've just noticed a bunch of other things in the list, like email addresses, `mailto:` links, some of it malformed (e.g. with a `.` suffix).)

Comment: @Sparhawk You should see this https://ptpb.pw/MFx_.png

Comment: Oooh… I was lacking `perl-curses-ui`. I now see the same as you, and it works fine. Thanks again for your help.